# Get text to jtextfield From clipboard Java

Tags: java, user-interface, clipboard

How to get text from clipboard and set that text to the jtextfield in java? 
want to always update jtextfield when program running.

Comment: provide some more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().addFlavorListener(new FlavorListener() {

                    public void flavorsChanged(FlavorEvent e) {
                        String data = null;
                        try {

                            data = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                                    .getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {

                        } catch (IOException ex) {

                        }
                        jTextField1.setText(data);

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

As it explained in http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-get-a-string-from-the-clipboard.html you just need to use java Toolkit and assign the text using setText in jTextField

```
package test;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GetStringFromClipboard {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
        String result = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        JTextField tf= new JTextField(20);
        tf.setText(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: I want do it always. This is only one time.

Comment: you can use thread to make it works. Here is some good example for your problem http://www.coderanch.com/forums/posts/list/377833#1649854